# How to remove dust from tiny holes in mobile device?

Tags: dust

I have a Lenovo k4 note. I have dust particles collected in the small holes near the speakers. If you see the image, I have marked the places. 
Is there any quick way to clean it without needing to buy compressed air can specially for this? 
[image: check this image]

Comment: Do you own a vacuum cleaner?

Comment: yeah, hope that works.

Comment: Why cant you buy the compressed air?

Comment: @CaptainObvious Can't tell why this specific individual doesn't want to buy compressed air. However, I do know that in my area you sometimes have to show ID to buy it. This is because people will buy compressed air and then get high off of it. So... That is a possibility

Answer (score 5):

Use a soft toothbrush thin enough to get inside the holes marked followed by a vacuum pipe sucking all the dust out of those tiny holes.

**Soft toothbrush** will disturb the dust and break the binding or reduces the binding. And applying suction from a **vacuum cleaner** just after that will remove most of the dust from it.

Note: this will not be 100% clean as it is achieved by opening the parts and cleaning.

Thanks for bringing this up.

Stay clean, stay good..!

Answer (score 2):

The *other* end of the vacuum may work too -- the exhaust port (rather than the suction end). It functions almost the same as a compressed air canister.

Comment: Why do you want to force dust into the phone?

Comment: @Paparazzi Interesting assumption. You're saying this wouldn't do what a can of compressed air would?

Comment: Interesting assumption I would use a can of gas.

Comment: You're right - I shouldn't have assumed that you would use a can of gas. But I do know that thousands of people use a can of gas to clean dust out of electronics, and I thought it would effectively clean dust out of small holes because of the turbulence / chaos of the air / wind within the hole. Does it not do that?  Does it actually pack dust in more firmly?  (I'm going to go Google that.)

Comment: Use air when the dust has some place to go.  Here you would just be packing it up against the speaker.  Could even tear the speaker.

Comment: Compressed air could tear the speaker, that's true. The air coming out of a vacuum is way less powerful ... but it could still tear the speaker.  However, I Googled "does compressed air work on headphone jack". The top 2 sites listed a few ways to clean dust out of headphone jacks, and they both listed compressed air as the #1 method.

Comment: You do know a headphone jack is different than speaker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46368/discussion-between-brettfromla-and-paparazzi).

Comment: Let's not - I have nothing more for you

Comment: It was recommended by the site.  I just clicked "OK".

Comment: Cool - got no problems - just have nothing else to add

Comment: @BrettFromLA If you force it into the phone you can't see it any more, and the original problem is essentially solved. It won't cause a problem in there, and you'll have a new phone in < 2 years anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Just spray it out with electronics cleaner then shake it out.

Here's an oversized picture to magically turn this from NAA into something legit:

[image]

Give it some distance; you don't want to puncture the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Try a vacuum cleaner, but keep some space between the phone and vacuum, about a finger width to prevent damage.